# Sonar-Runner On Windows not working

Tags: java, php, mysql, jdbc, sonarqube

I have setup sonar on my windows 7 , server starts fine.
Using sonar runner for my php project.But getting " Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'". Searched on google but didn't find any proper way.
I've created new user under mysql with the name of sonar and same password.
This is the sonar-runner.properties code

```
sonar.jdbc.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
```

Comment: Does your Sonarqube-Server run successfully using the MySQL-DB? YOu have to configure the Server as well to use MySQL. Could you please add your Servers DB configuration to your question?